# Validation date in specific range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

Hi I have model **bought_details** and **entry_types**.

```
# Table name: bought_details
#
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  bought_data   :date             not null
#  end_on        :date             not null
#  entry_type_id :integer
#  person_id     :integer
#  start_on      :date
#  cost          :decimal(5, 2)    not null

# Table name: entry_types
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  kind         :string           not null
#  kind_details :string           not null
#  description  :text
#  price        :decimal(5, 2)    not null
```

What I want to have:

If I register new purchase e.g. person with id 1 buy pass(entry_type id: 1) for 1 month(start_on: 20.04.2016 end_on: 20.05.2016).

I want create validation to protect buy new pass(entry_type kind == "Pass", in a database I have few entry type object with kind equals "Pass"), when start_on or end_on is between 20.04.2016 and 20.05.2016r. with simply alert "You already have valid pass".

How can I resolve my problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show please what have you tried so far.

Comment: You can define a validate function on your model like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836000/how-to-validate-a-models-date-attribute-against-a-specific-range-evaluated-at).

Comment: What's that `r.` after your dates?

Comment: @Stefan it's polish translation of year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try `validates_timeliness` gem?
https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness

It can simply validate date ranges.

```
validates_date :start_on, after: lambda { (DateTime.now - 1.month }, before: lambda { (DateTime.now + 1.month }
```